# Using a Function in a WHERE clause to return Nth Number Weekday of Month

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, where-clause

Good Afternoon,

I have this funtion that gives me the Nth number weekday of the month but struggling to use it in my WHERE clause to filter out onlt the dates that apply to this funtion. The function code is this:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetNthWeekdayOfMonth]
 (
     @theDate DATETIME,
     @theWeekday TINYINT,
     @theNth SMALLINT
 )
 RETURNS DATETIME
 BEGIN
     RETURN  (
                 SELECT  theDate
                 FROM    (
                             SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 7 * @theNth - 7 * SIGN(SIGN(@theNth) + 1) +(@theWeekday + 6 - DATEDIFF(DAY, '17530101', DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, @theNth, @theDate), '19000101')) % 7) % 7, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, @theNth, @theDate), '19000101')) AS theDate
                             WHERE   @theWeekday BETWEEN 1 AND 7
                                     AND @theNth IN (-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                         ) AS d
                 WHERE   DATEDIFF(MONTH, theDate, @theDate) = 0
             )
 END
```

So I want to use the function in my WHERE clause as stated above.
How do I do this as currently I am getting the:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.
```

It works fine when in teh SELECT statement on a date field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your your query where you are using this function

Comment: Oh my, please build a calendar table.

Comment: Calendar tables will change your life!

Comment: Just like the numbers table. You'll never look at your children the same.

Comment: Calendar table is in the making and once I get everyone in agreement that we need one. I want to build one with Fiscal year etc, basically to cover everything you need from a calendar table :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your function like below.

Assuming you have a table *t* with a date column *d* and you want to find the date *d* that is the *4th Sunday in October*. (This assumes that the week starts on day 1, Monday).

```
select d from t
where d = dbo.fnGetNthWeekdayOfMonth('2014-10-01',7,4)
```

If you want to test it and don't have and appropriate table with a date column you can test with the sample code below.

```
;with Dates (my_date) as (
    select DATEADD(day,number,'2014-10-01') 
    from master..spt_values where number < 31 and type='p'
)
select * from Dates 
where my_date = dbo.fnGetNthWeekdayOfMonth('2014-10-01',7,4)
```

Result:

```
my_date
2014-10-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks jpw. I must be having one of those days....need to have a break from my screen argghhhh